# Abbott: Which type of proof is this?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

Let $x_1=2$ and define $$ x_{n+1}:=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}\right).$$Show that $x_n^2\geq 2$.
This was my working 
Suppose inductively that $x_n^2\geq 2$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$. Then
$$x_{n+1}^2=\left(\frac{x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}}{2}\right)^2\underbrace{\geq}_{\text{AM-GM}} x_n\left(\frac{2}{x_n}\right)=2. $$
I wonder how can we prove some statement without using inductive hypothesis? (by induction)
Actually I saw one post on MSE ([Using induction to show that if $x_n^2 \geq 2$, then $x_{n+1}^2 \geq 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2116406/1048756)) which helped me to solved this problem by some nice technique. However I saw the solution in authors solution manual where he writes
[image]

**MY QUESTION**: Which type of proof is this (one mentioned above and mine)? If this is induction and why not using inductive hypothesis?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality

Comment: @Khosrotash sorry I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: I think your question is about AM-GM usage, did I get right? (If not , I do apologize)

Comment: Your proof uses AM-GM inequality while his proof doesn't. And the two proofs are very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being rigorous, your proof is not by induction. When we are doing proofs by induction, we need to do "three steps". In order:

1. Prove the base, i.e., prove that the assertion is true for $n=0$ (or $n=1$ in some cases)
2. Suppose that the assertion is true for $n$.
3. Using the fact that is true for $n$, prove the assertion for $n+1$.

If we are done with the previous three steps, then, by the induction principle, the assertion is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now, the proof in the solution manual is a direct proof, i.e., the author chooses a fixed, but arbitrary, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and prove directly, only using the definition, that the required property holds for $n$. As the only property of $n$ that was used was the fact that is a natural number, this is an argument that works for all natural numbers. So, you don't require induction. Is it clear now?

Comment: Oh I see. So the author proved $x_n^2\geq 2$ holds just by picking arbitrary but fixed $n$. But the author proved $x_{n+1}^2\geq 2$ instead of $x_n^2$ why? My honest guess it proving either of them is same since $n$ is arbitrary. Am i thinking right? (Because for $x_n^2\geq 2$ we use $x_{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n})$)

Comment: Yes. You are right. Moreover, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ notice that $n+1\geq 2$. Thus, the only case that remains unsolved is $n=1$. But $x_1=2$ and this also has the desired property.